# Setting Table View Cell Image

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've set the image for the cells in my table view, but the lines dividing the cells aren't showing. What have I done wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *mbTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BarButton.png"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mbTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:mbTableIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }

    // cell.backgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundView = image;

    cell.textLabel.text = [mbTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: I've logged my separator style and color

2013-05-20 07:28:40.392 KFBNewsroom[1274:c07] cell separator style: 2 separator color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.67 0.67 0.67 1
2013-05-20 07:28:40.393 KFBNewsroom[1274:c07] cell separator style: 2 separator color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.67 0.67 0.67 1
2013-05-20 07:28:40.393 KFBNewsroom[1274:c07] cell separator style: 2 separator color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.67 0.67 0.67 1

EDIT: Screenshot of the problem
[image]

EDIT:  I ended up resolving the problem by adding a 1 pixel line to the bottom of my image.

Comment: "I've set the image for the cells in my table view" Where did you do this, I don't see it in your post.

Comment: I set cell.backgroundView = image;

Comment: Sorry, missed that. So what's the problem? You don't see that image? It's not clear what not seeing the dividing lines has to do with your problem.

Comment: I only don't see the cell dividing lines when setting this background image.  Before I was using the CustomCellBackground that I created and could see where the cells were divided.  When I use this new background image, I don't see the line that separates one cell from another.

Comment: Could it be that the image has colors that make the line hard to see? I tried your code with a couple of different images, and they all worked OK. Try changing the color of the separator to see if that makes it visible.

Comment: I tried tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; and I still don't see the separator lines.

Comment: I think white is the default color of the line, so that wouldn't change anything. Can you post an image of your cells somewhere?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-vCzSnQb_YzZ19DREtQUmNnYzQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30232/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-user2029585)

Comment: try adding frame to the image. the image might be a little too big (height) for the cell height you set.

Comment: if you image size is large then keep it small and if you want bigger image set to cell then increase the cell height.as per my code given below.

Comment: is this app released?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return 50;
}
```

this delegate method for increase the height of your tableview cell.
you may try this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tableview properties in XIB, check if Separator has been set as 'None'. In that case, you need to set it as 'Single Line' from the drop down ..

Answer (score 0):

Set property of your tableView from coding

```
yourTableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

Using xib

[image]

Or increase your tableView row height (more then your image height)

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: whats the height of your images?

Comment: comment this line cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];

Comment: can you please attach screenshot

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what is happening. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-vCzSnQb_YzZ19DREtQUmNnYzQ/edit

Comment: whats your cell height and image height?